# New activity after camera intent

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

i have:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foto);

    Intent intentFotocamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()); //creo un timestamp univoco

    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs(); //creo un nuovo album

    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png"); //concateno
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

    intentFotocamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(intentFotocamera, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Now, when the user presses the photo confirmation button (and then is saved locally) I would like to create a new activity because I want to print this photo in my app.

How do I create new activity?

Comment: See this [Camera activity tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the override method onActivityResult() start the new activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The user picked a contact.
        // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

        // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST`?

Comment: He ment `CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE` this should be accepted answer.

Comment: I just used the example from google, forgot to edit that part. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open new activity and show the photo which is taken recently?

Here is how you can do it.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

                    "handle here"

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a answer! Comments should be posted in comment section